# Maximum value of $\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^3}+\frac{1}{(2b+c+a)^3}+\frac{1}{(2c+a+b)^3}$ if $abc=1.$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How would you find the maximum value of $\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^3}+\frac{1}{(2b+c+a)^3}+\frac{1}{(2c+a+b)^3}$ when $abc=1$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers? (if it exists)

Again inspired by: [The maximum of $\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^2}+\frac{1}{(2b+c+a)^2}+\frac{1}{(2c+a+b)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310969/the-maximum-of-frac12abc2-frac12bca2-frac12cab2).

Comment: are $a,b,c$ positive real numbers?

Comment: Yes oops, I'll add that.

Comment: Ah, should be up front in the question, not after the "Another similar problem"

Comment: By the way, "last two" assumes you have a continuous readership, which is not the case here. People who read one question might not have read the others. Just state your question - it lets readers quickly determine if they can help. Here, one has to read past the prologue to get to your question, but the prologue doesn't help us help you.

Comment: I found $$\frac{3}{64}$$ for $a=b=c=1$ but I am having hard time proving it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=b=c=1$ then we'll get a value $\frac{3}{64}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, by C-S and AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^3}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a^3+b^3+c^3+9a(ab+ac+bc)+3bc(a+b+c)+3a(2(b^2+c^2)+a(b+c))}\leq$$
$$\leq\tfrac{1}{(10+27+9+18)^2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\tfrac{10^2}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}+\tfrac{27^2}{9a(ab+ac+bc)}+\tfrac{9^2}{3bc(a+b+c)}+\tfrac{18^2}{3a(2(b^2+c^2)+a(b+c))}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\tfrac{1}{64^2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\tfrac{100}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}+\tfrac{81}{a(ab+ac+bc)}+\tfrac{27}{bc(a+b+c)}+\tfrac{108}{a((b+c)^2+a(b+c))}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{25}{1024}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}+\frac{27}{1024abc}+\frac{27}{1024}\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{abc(b+c)(a+b+c)}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{25}{1024}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}+\frac{27}{1024abc}+\frac{27}{1024}\sum_{cyc}\frac{\frac{(b+c)^2}{4}}{abc(b+c)(a+b+c)}=$$
$$=\frac{25}{1024}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}+\frac{81}{2048abc}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{25}{1024}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}+\frac{81}{2048abc}\leq\frac{3}{64abc}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a^3+b^3+c^3}\leq\frac{3}{10abc}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8a+b+c}\leq\frac{3}{10},$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives such that $abc=1$.

Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(v^2)\geq0$, where $f$ is a linear function.

But the linear function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $v^2$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $ b=a$ and $c=\frac{1}{a^2}$.

We obtain $$(a-1)^2(27a^4-11a^3-49a^2+24a+12)\geq0,$$
which is easy enough:
$$27a^4-11a^3-49a^2+24a+12=$$
$$=11(a^4-a^3-a^2+a)+12(a^4-2a^2+1)+4a^4-14a^2+13a\geq$$
$$\geq a\left(4a^3+2\cdot\frac{13}{2}-14a\right)\geq a^2\left(3\sqrt[3]{13^2}-14\right)>0.$$
Done!

Also, we can use the following way.

Let $a^{\frac{3}{4}}=x$, $b^{\frac{3}{4}}=y$ and $c^{\frac{3}{4}}=z$.

Hence, $xyz=1$ and by AM-GM, P-M and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^3}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+3\cdot\frac{a+b+c}{3}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{64\left(\sqrt[4]{a\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3}\right)^3}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{64x\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3}=\frac{xy+xz+yz}{64\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^2\cdot\frac{x+y+z}{3}}\leq\frac{3}{64}.$$
Another way.

By AM-GM, AM-GM and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^3}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(2a+b+c)^2(2a+b+c)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{16a\sqrt{bc}(2a+b+c)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{bc}}{16(a+b+a+c)}\leq\frac{1}{32}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{bc}{(a+b)(a+c)}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{32}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+b}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+c}}\leq\frac{1}{64}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{c}{a+c}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{64}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{a}{b+a}\right)=\frac{3}{64}.$$

Comment: hy I hope you doing well , please what motivate the choice of the coefficient 10,27 , 9 and 18 ?

Comment: @oty We know that the equality occurs for $a=b=c$ and we want to save this thing after using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

Let $3s=a+b+c\geqslant3$, as $abc=1$; then we need to show
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac1{(3s+a)^3}\leqslant \frac3{16}$$

Let $f(x)=\dfrac1{16}-\dfrac1{(3s+x)^3}-\dfrac3{256s^3}\log x$, it is enough to show for $x\in (0,3s), s\geqslant 1$ that $f(x)\geqslant0$.

That is not hard as $f’(x)\leqslant 0$ and $f(3s)$ increases with $s$ with a positive value for $s=1$.